# Find the number given its remainders

Tags: mathematics, calculation-puzzle, number-theory

I am wondering if there is a structured way to solve this kind of problem:

There is a number $n$

- $n$ divided by $m$ (m is not given) has remainder 5
- $n$ divided by $m+1$ has remainder 1
- $n$ divided by $m+2$ has remainder 7
- $n$ divided by $m+3$ has remainder 1
- $n$ divided by $m+4$ has remainder 1
- $n$ is between 300 and 500

and (only use it if you really need them):

- $n$ divided by $m+5$ has remainder 7
- $n$ divided by $m+6$ has remainder 5

There is (at least one)  solution to this puzzle, I am not sure if there are more than one. but how to find it?

From the given, can I deduce that $n$ is odd?

But is there more to know about $n$ and are there ways to find $n$ that do not rely on brute force?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I believe the only solution is

> $n=397$, $m=8$

Proof

> Consider the number $n-1$. This is divisible by $m+3$ and $m+4$.
>  These numbers are coprime if $m+3 > 1$ and, in this case, $n-1$ is divisible by $(m+3)(m+4)$. But $22*23 > 500$ so $m+3<22$ i.e, $m<19$. 
>  It is also the case that $n-1$ is divisible by $m+1$ and gcd$(m+1, m+3) \le 2$ and gcd$(m+1, m+4) \le 3$ so that $n-1 \ge \frac{m+1}{6}(m+3)(m+4)$ 
>  From this inequality, we find that $n < 500$ only if $m < 12$. 
>  Since $n$ divided by $m$ has remainder $5$  we must presume that $5 <m$ and so $5 < m  < 12$ i.e, $6$ possibilities. 
>  $m=6 \Rightarrow m+1 = 7$ and then $n-1$ must be divisible by $7*9*10 > 500$ 
>  $m=7 \Rightarrow m+1 = 8$ and then $n-1$ is divisible by at least $4*10*11 = 440 \Rightarrow n=441$. 
>  $m=8 \Rightarrow m+1 = 9$ and then $n-1$ is divisible by $3*11*12 = 396 \Rightarrow n=397$ . 
>  $m=9 \Rightarrow m+1 = 10$ and then $n-1$ is divisible by $5*12*13 >500$
>  $m=10 \Rightarrow m+1 = 11$ and then $n-1$ is divisible by $11*13*14 >500$ 
>  $m=11 \Rightarrow m+1 = 12$ and then $n-1$ is divisible by $2*14*15 =420 \Rightarrow n=421$ 
>  Hence there are just three cases to check $n=441, 397$ and $421$ and only $n=397$ works in which case $m=8$ (in fact $397$ is the only one that leaves remainder $5$ when divided by the corresponding $m$).

Answer (score 6):

Easy proof that `n` is odd:

> n has an odd remainder when divided by both m and m+1.
>  One of m and m+1 is even.
>  n has an odd remainder when divided by an even number.
>  n must be odd.

Answer (score 2):

Using brute force I found that

> n = 397, when m = 8

```
begin = 300
end = 500
pairs = {0:5, 1:1, 2:7, 3:1, 4:1, 5:7, 6:5}
ns = []
ms = []
for i in xrange(begin, end + 1):
    for m in xrange(1, 1000):
        for k, v in pairs.items():
            if i % (m + k) != v:
                break
        else:
            ns.append(i)
            ms.append(m)
print ns
print ms
```

Comment: First off all the OP asks about a method that does not involve brute force. Second, why do you search for m between 1 and 1000? You can start with 8 (since the biggest reminder is 7) and stop at `n-1`since m < n.

Comment: I am trying to see if there is any pattern from brute forcing. I'm sorry I am no mathematician.

Comment: Marius, you have to start at m=6, not 8, because it is dividing by (m+2), not m, that gives a remainder of 7.

Answer (score 1):

Partial.
I can only prove that n is odd for now.

> $n = m*k + 5$
>  If m is even then n is odd because the line above can be written as
>  $n = 2*a *k + 5$  or $n = 2*(a*k+2) + 1$ which is odd.
>  if m is odd then we move to the next one
>  $n=(m+1)*k + 1$ (different k as the one above).
>  This can be written as
>  $n=(2*a+1+1)*k + 1$ or $n = 2*(a+1)*k+1$ so n is an odd number.

[edit]
An easier proof that n is odd:

> $m+3$ divides $n-1$ and $m+4$ divides $n-1$.
>  this means that
>  $n-1 = (m+3)*(m+4)$.
>  the product of 2 consecutive numbers is an even number so
>  $n-1 = 2*k$ which results in $n = 2*k+1$

Working on the rest.

Answer (score 1):

In general it cannot be solved. Given one remainder we have three unknowns: m, the number we must multiply m by to get it within m of n and n itself. With each remainder we add adds another unknown (the number we must multiply m+1 by to get within m+1 of n). Therefore we will always have 2 more unknowns than we have equations.

Another way you can think about it is there are infinite possible values of n and each remainder we are given we reduce this number by factor of m+x, sadly that still gives us infinite possible values of n.

Whilst you will always be able to find solutions to n there will always be infinite correct solutions to n unless provided with two other bounding conditions. i.e.  x < n < y as has been done and solved for in other answers.

Answer (score 0):

The search space can be reduced to `n = 6k+1`.

`n-1` must be a multiple of six, because

- `n-1` must be even because `m+3` and `m+4` both divide `n-1`;
- `n-1` must be a multiple of 3,, because one of m, m+1, or m+2 must be a multiple of 3 (and `(n-7) % 3 ≡ (n-1) % 3`)

---

A (much) more efficient search can be achieved by iterating over potential `m` rather than potential `n`.

Note that

- `n-1` must be a multiple of `r=lcm(m+1,m+3,m+4)`.
- the range of possible solutions is bounded by `s=lcm(m,m+1,m+2,m+3,m+4)`; if a solution `n` exists for a given `m`, then `n + k×s` for all integers `k` must also be solutions.

It follows that at most `m×(m+2)` potential solutions `k×r` need be tested for each `m`. However since solutions are of the form `k×r+1` and are bounded between 300 & 500, our search for `k` can iterate over just `[ ⎡299/r⎤ ... ⎣499/r⎦ ]`

| m | r | s | k<sub>min</sub> = ⎡299/r⎤ | k<sub>max</sub> = ⎣499/r⎦ | k×r+1 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 6 | 630 | 2520 | 1 | 0 | *(none)* |
| 7 | 440 | 27720 | 1 | 1 | 441 |
| 8 | 396 | 3960 | 1 | 1 | **397** |
| 9 | 780 | 25740 | 1 | 0 | *(none)* |
| 10 | 2002 | 60060 | 1 | 0 | *(none)* |
| 11 | 420 | 60060 | 1 | 1 | 421 |

So in practice this approach can solve the problem after checking just two `k×r+1` candidate values for remainder after division by `m` and `m+2`.

We can stop increasing `m` once we're satisfied that `r>500` must apply to all larger `m`; a brute-force scan of `6≤m≤496` reveals that `m>11 ⇒ lcm(m+1,m+3,m+4)>500`.